# parse number from the string

Tags: c++, c, stl

Say I have the line in this format

"word word    12  YR" or "word word    10 MO"

and I want to convert it to

char * containing either "12Y" or "10M" respectively.

The format is two words followed by numerical followed by the word denoting the year or the month. words are space/tab separated. Currently, I am playing around with the strtok function

Thanks

Comment: You should be a little bit more clear about the sorts of strings you need to process, and whether they'll all be well-formed, and what you want to happen if they're not well-formed. Also your tags seem wrong. C has not "stl" and "cpp" means C preprocessor, not C++.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking here, or what you have already tried.

Comment: sorry, I clarified the format in the descriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is (no error checking, using `boost`):

```
  string s = "word word 10 MR";
  string res;
  tokenizer<> tok(s);
  tokenizer<>::iterator iter = tok.begin();
  while(iter != tok.end())
  {
      try
      {
        int n = lexical_cast<int>(*iter);
      }
      catch(bad_lexical_cast& e)
      {
          ++iter;
          continue;
      }

      break;
  }

  res = *iter;
  ++iter;
  res = res + (*iter)[0];
```

Non-boost solution:

```
  using namespace std;
  string s = "word word 10 MR";
  string res;

  stringstream ss(s);
  istream_iterator<string> iter(ss);
  istream_iterator<string> end;

  while(iter != end)
  {
      istringstream iss(*iter);
      int n;
      iss>>n;

      if( ! iss.fail())
      {
          break;
      }
      ++iter;
  }

  res = *iter;
  ++iter;
  res = res + (*iter)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

for ANSI C 89 have a look at:

```
char *str="word word 12 YR", *p=str, tmp[MAXSTR], yourstr[MAXYOURSTR]={};
...
while( 1==sscanf(p,"%s",tmp) ) {
  if( *yourstr )
  {
    yourstr[strlen(yourstr)]=*tmp;
    break;
  }
  else
  if( 1==sscanf(tmp,"%[0-9]*") )
    strcpy(yourstr,tmp);
  p+=strlen(tmp)+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize it with space as the delimiter.  Concatenate the second-to-last token, and a space, and the first character of the last token.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your string for spaces.  Throw away the first 2 words.  Combine the 3rd term with the first letter of the 4th term.  strtok or just a forloop and some counts would take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org) library and do it with a regexp.

Comment: If it's C++, he could also use boost::regex, it has the advantage to be included in the next release of the C++ standard.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. ( http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html )

Comment: I cannot use this sort of libraries, nor boost. Let's use what's available within the standard

Answer (score 0):

[user411313's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856637/parse-number-from-the-string/3858473#3858473) made me think of this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char result[9];
  char w[4][1000]; /* temporary */
  const char *src = "word word 12 YR"; /* "word word 10 MO"; */

  if (sscanf(src, "%s%s%s%s", w[0], w[1], w[2], w[3]) == 4) {
    size_t len;
    strcpy(result, w[2]);
    result[len = strlen(result)] = *(w[3]);
    result[len + 1] = 0;
  }
  printf("result: [%s]\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```